# error while creating a new logging instance in LogDNA on IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

I tried to create a new logging instance on LogDNA service on IBM cloud , although I chose lite plan 
It is always failing with error message

Your account does not allow the use of non-lite plans. You can upgrade by adding a credit card to your account or you can select the lite plan if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, it is being addressed.  You could work around this by upgrading your account with a credit card.  No charges will be assessed for the free lite plan for the logging with logdna service.  Or you can wait for the problem to be addressed.